# Can high energy galactic neutrinos harm us?

Tags: astrophysics, neutrinos

The neutrinos that are generated from the supernova are in the order of Peta eV, which is very large; when they reach the earth surface and get contact with earthly bodies, do they make any harm, if not why ?

Comment: A neutrino could cause a beta decay in a nucleus moving an element one step further in the periodic table and typically make it unstable and radioactive. I hope experts will answer how this probability depends on the neutrino energy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a relevant ["what-if?" article](https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/). It cites a paper by [Andrew Karam : "Gamma and neutrino radiation dose from gamma ray bursts and nearby supernovae"](http://web.archive.org/web/20120313045458/http://www.andrewkaram.com/andy/pdf/HPJ.pdf) .

According to this paper, the neutrino radiation dose at a distance of one parsec from a supernova would be around half a nanosievert. At $2.4 \mathrm{AU}$, the radiation dose from neutrinos alone would be lethal ($\mathrm{4 sieverts}$).

If [Spica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spica) (one of the nearest stars to the Sun that has enough mass to end its life in a Type II supernova) went supernova, we would get about $ 4 Sv ⋅ (2.4\mathrm{AU}/250\mathrm{ly})^2 ≈ 100 \mathrm{fSv}$ of neutrino radiation. This represents less than 4 milliseconds of the average [background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation).

From the paper :

> The  average  energy  of  neutrinos  released  in supernovae
>   explosions is between 5 MeV (Schramm and Brown  1990)  and  15  MeV 
>   (Sutaria  and  Ray  1997).

It's not clear where your $\mathrm{Pev}$ order of magnitude comes from. Scaling the previous quantity by $\mathrm{1PeV/(15MeV)}$, the neutrino radiation dose would be around $6 \mathrm{µSv}$. This quantity would be perfectly measurable but not harmful.

Neutrinos are extremely hard to detect, it makes sense that even highly energetic neutrinos from a few parsecs away would not interact with our body in any way.

The effect of other particles from a near-Earth supernova would be [much stronger and potentially dangerous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26579/148854).

Comment: Might be useful to compare this with the effect of other [near Earth supernova effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-Earth_supernova).

Answer (score 0):

This is a "knock me over with a feather" scenario. Even moles and scientific notation would have a lot of trouble calculating the amount of neutrinos required to even *interact* with one of our atoms. (We're assuming all of them hit space somewhere in your general volume.)

Comment: $\rm PeV$ neutrinos actually have a [much larger interaction cross section](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.7513.pdf) than solar neutrinos. It doesn't take many neutrinos at that level to get some interaction with your atoms.